# .NET MAUI I need Entry to not open the keyboard but not be read only

Tags: .net, keyboard, maui

I'm working on an app for a special device that is not a typical phone. This device inputs text without using the digital keyboard of a phone; instead, it utilizes QR codes and the physical keyboard of the device. I need to implement an 'entry' field that is not read-only but does not trigger the keyboard to open when it is focused. I'm uncertain if this is possible.

Comment: How do you scan QR codes after focusing Entries though?

Comment: that why I say the device is not a regular phone, It's a weird machine, with a QR lector that reads special QRs and writes text as if it was written by hand

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Maui Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-8.0) to set the [ShowSoftInputOnFocus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.widget.textview.showsoftinputonfocus?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13) property.

```
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
    {
#if ANDROID
        handler.PlatformView.ShowSoftInputOnFocus=false;
#endif
    });
}
```